# What do the numbers in brackets mean on the iptables-save output?

Tags: iptables

What do the `[368:102354]`, `[0:0]` and `[92952:20764374]` in my `iptables` output file mean?

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [368:102354]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [92952:20764374]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per https://serverfault.com/a/373875/145318:

> The [0:0] or [1280:144299] or whatever are the count of
>   [Packets:Bytes] that have been trough the chain . They are saved when
>   you run an iptables-save command and are used by the iptables-restore
>   command to initialise the counters.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you mark the answer as correct then.